# Merge string to find variable name

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, variables

Lets say i have 3 labels named LBL_1, LBL_2 and LBL_3.

Then i have a function that makes a randomized choice of 1,2 and 3.

How can i combine that value with a label name?

Like this

```
Dim NR As Integer = MyOneToThreeRandomizer()
'Now NR is 1,2 or 3

LBL_ & NR.ToString(or something) & .Text = "Hello world!"
```

I can of course do something like this;

```
Dim NR As Integer = MyOneToThreeRandomizer()
If NR = 1 Then
    LBL_1.Text = "Hello World!"
Else If NR = 2 Then
    LBL_2.Text.....
....And so on
```

But in this case it could be up to 80 numbers so this feels really bad.

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, and there are a couple of similar questions, but I can't find a true duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your labels to a panel and acces them trough the children. Then u can access them by index.

Answer (score 3):

Put your labels in an Array and then access them by Index.

```
Dim myLabelArray As String() = {"label1", "label2", "label3"}

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

'Some flavour of loop

    Dim NR As Integer = MyOneToThreeRandomizer()

    sb.Append(myLabelArray(NR-1))

'End loop
```

---

If you have `System.Windows.Forms.Label`*s*, you can add them to the *stage* programmatically, in a loop, while you also put them in your `labelArray`.

Comment: That would be adding each label individually to the array, basically the same.

Comment: Nope: `Dim myLabelArray As String() = {"label1", "label2", "label3"}`

Comment: You've to put those labels somewhere, haven't you? Or maybe, I did not understand what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: I think he means there labels on a forms, easiest to get them trough the children imo, could be i mis-interpreted as wel :)

Comment: In that case, probably the best way is to add labels programatically. You add them in a loop that also puts them in your `labelArray`.

Comment: that would be the best solution indeed :) ++

Comment: Yea, i have all the labels in a form all named "and ready". It's not my work from the beginning, I would have made a loop of some kind to get all these labels out, but i don't wanna touch this stuff more then i need too. I did how ever put all these labels in a panel that i looped, and this works. Good solution. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim NR As Integer = MyOneToThreeRandomizer()
Dim lbls() As Label = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("LBL_" & NR, True), Label())

If lbls.Length > 0 Then
    lbls(0).Text = "Hello world!"
End If
```

Comment: This looks interesting! Have to test this even if the panel-solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: If all your lbl controls are added to the form directly, I would change the True to False in the Find method for performance. This should also work on other controls. If your labels are on the panel try MyPanel.Controls.Find(...)

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each ctr As Control In Container.Controls
   If ctr.Name = "LBL_" & NR.ToString Then
      CType(ctr, Label).Text = "Hello World"
   End If
Next
```